# Odoo Javascript, how can I access to the value of this object?

Tags: javascript, odoo, point-of-sale

So I'm workin in POS module in Odoo 14, I've created a field in 'pos.order' called 'ticket_number' which is related to the id of the record. So if the id is 15, the ticket_number will be 15 too. This field is already charged to the 'pos.order' model:

```
odoo.define("custom_pos_order.models", function (require) {
"use strict";

    var models = require('point_of_sale.models');

    models.load_fields('pos.order', 'id');
    models.load_fields('pos.order', 'ticket_number');

});
```

My purpose is to show this new field in the voucher when you get to the last screen:
[image: POS Last screen]

As you can see, in the red box I would like to show this field.

But, as this field is not native, I have to workaround with some Javascript. I have this object in the console, and this object contains the value of the id of the order:
[image: JS Object]

So my question is, how can I access to that value in JS code, to assign it to a new variable?

Comment: What is the html id of that red box, if one exists?
Instead of creating an additional field, why not just put the id field in the view?

Comment: because when the view is rendered, is not with 'pos.order' fields... the 'point_of_sale' module gives a different dict of values called "receipt" for that view, which doesn't have the field "ticket_number" neither the field "id"

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below line to load fields in a single line instead writing two and more lines for each fields

```
models.load_fields("pos.order",['id','ticket_number']);
```

Also mention the field in the below function to get it in the receipt screen

```
get_receipt_render_env: function() {
    var order = this.pos.get_order();
    return {
        widget: this,
        pos: this.pos,
        order: order,
        receipt: order.export_for_printing(),
        orderlines: order.get_orderlines(),
        paymentlines: order.get_paymentlines(),
    };
},
```

Comment: Sorry but this didn't help me at all. Where am I supossed to mention "validated_orders_name_server_id_map" to get its value?